# Running multiply Anova and/or T-Test on variables in one dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, anova, t-test

I've the a data frame containing different items (and it's cost) and also it's subsequent groupings. I would like to run an Anova and/or T-Test for each item based on their groupings to see if their mean differs. Anybody knows how to do this in R?

A sample of the dataframe is as follow:

| Item | Cost | Grouping |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Book A | 7 | A |
| Book A | 9 | B |
| Book A | 6 | A |
| Book A | 7 | B |
| Book B | 4 | A |
| Book B | 6 | B |
| Book B | 5 | A |
| Book B | 3 | C |
| Book C | 5 | C |
| Book C | 4 | A |
| Book C | 7 | C |
| Book C | 2 | B |
| Book C | 2 | B |
| Book D | 4 | A |
| Book D | 2 | C |
| Book D | 9 | C |
| Book D | 4 | A |

The output should be a simple table (or any similar table) as follows

| Item | P-Value (from ANOVA/t-test) (H0: Mean same for all groupings) |
| --- | --- |
| Book A | xxx |
| Book B | xxx |
| Book C | xxx |
| Book D | xxx |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there's only 2 groupings, then T-Test would do, else I would use ANOVA

Comment: You are planning to do a lot of statistical tests. You should also plan to do multiple comparison adjustment of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `anova_test` from the `rstatix` package like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(Item = c("Book A", "Book A", "Book A", "Book A", "Book B", "Book B", "Book B", "Book B"),
                 Cost = c(7,9,6,7,4,6,5,3),
                 Grouping = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C"))

library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)
df %>% 
  group_by(Item) %>%
  anova_test(Cost ~ Grouping)
#> Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
#> Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 8
#>   Item   Effect     DFn   DFd     F     p `p<.05`   ges
#> * <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 Book A Grouping     1     2   1.8 0.312 ""      0.474
#> 2 Book B Grouping     2     1   4.5 0.316 ""      0.9
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the rstatix package. Is there a similar one for t.test as well?

Comment: Hi @Luther_Proton, yes you could use the function t_test!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of dealing with multiple ANOVA, t-tests and worrisome (and potentially questionable) p-values, I would fit a single generalised linear mixed-effect model with `group` as a random effect. This is easy to do in a fully Bayesian way using `rstanarm`, which gives full posterior distributions for the means of every `item`. Instead of worrying about the suitability & interpretability of (multiple) hypothesis tests, we can then compare posterior distributions for the means directly.

```r
library(rstanarm)
model <- stan_glmer(cost ~ 0 + item + (1 | group), data = df)
```

We can summarise the mean posterior distributions by showing the posterior median and 90% posterior uncertainty intervals per `item`.

```r
library(broom.mixed)
tidy(model, conf.int = TRUE) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = term)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = estimate)) + 
    geom_linerange(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high))
```

[image]

Or as a table

```r
tidy(mode, conf.int = TRUE)
## A tibble: 4 × 5
#  term       estimate std.error conf.low conf.high
#  <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 itemBook A     7.28      1.17     5.09      9.40
#2 itemBook B     4.44      1.16     2.27      6.45
#3 itemBook C     3.88      1.05     1.89      5.75
#4 itemBook D     4.63      1.21     2.41      6.71
```

Here,

- `estimate` is the posterior median,
- `std.error` is the posterior MAD, and
- `conf.low` and `conf.high` are the lower and upper bounds of the 90% posterior uncertainty interval.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this insightful sharing! Will take note of this approach!